# Gmail application displays font size and color wrong

Tags: php, css, html-table, gmail, html-email

I have the php/html code with tables. It looks perfectly OK in yahoo, gmail etc but looks so messed up with weird green colors and wrong varying font sizes when opened in gmail application on mobile phone only. Any idea how this can be fixed? the link below consists of 2 screenshots. The one on left is how it looks on all email accounts including gmail. and the one on right is how it looks on gmail application on iPhone.

[Link for the screenshot](http://www.magentastorage.co.uk/mobile/images/photo%20%28c%29.png)

The code is as below:

```
<?php 
// Fixes the encoding to uf8 
function fixEncoding($in_str) 
{ 
  $cur_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($in_str) ; 
if($cur_encoding == "UTF-8" && mb_check_encoding($in_str,"UTF-8")) 
return $in_str; 
else 
return utf8_encode($in_str); 
} // fixEncoding 
?>
<?php


require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not     already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body = '<html><body>';
$body .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #fff; font-family: Arial; width:595px;     height:108px; font-size:115%; background-color:#ffffff;" cellpadding="10">';
$body .= "<tr><td style='text-align: center; text-align: middle; vertical-align: middle;      vertical-align: center'>
 <img style='border: 0px solid ;     'src='http://www.magentastorage.co.uk/mobile/images/emailheader.jpg'></a> </td></tr>";

 $body .= '</table>';

 $body .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #fff; font-family: Arial; width:595px; font-size:115%; background-color:#ffffff;" cellpadding="10"; position:relative; left:"20">';

$body .= "<tr><td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>Dear  " .$_GET["name"] ."," . "</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>Thank you for visiting our website and contacting us about your storage requirements. Below is a summary of your storage quotation:  </td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr> <td style='text-align: left; font-family: Arial; vertical-align: left;'>
 <img style='border: 0px solid ; ' src='http://www.magentastorage.co.uk/mobile/images/emailrequirements.png'> </td></tr>";

$body .= '</table>';

$body .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #fff; font-family: Arial; width:470px; font-size:115%; background-color:#ffffff;" cellpadding="10">';

    $body .= "<tr>";
$body .= "<td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>Unit Size:</td>";
$body .= "<td>";
$body .= $_GET["unitsize"];
$body .= "</td>";
$body .= "<td></td>";
$body .= "</tr>";


    $body .= '</table>';

$body .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #fff; font-family: Arial; width:595px; font-size:115%; background-color:#ffffff;" cellpadding="10">';

$body .= "<tr> <td style='text-align: left; font-family: Arial; vertical-align: left;'>
 <img style='border: 0px solid ; '
 src='http://www.magentastorage.co.uk/mobile/images/emailquotation.png'> </td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>" ."Weekly rental is" ." " ."&pound;" .$_GET["price"] ." "     ."</td> </tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>This quote includes VAT, insurance cover for up to" ." " ."£" .$_GET["insurance"] ." " ."and a padlock to secure your storage unit</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>" ."<strong>" ."**4 WEEKS FREE STORAGE**" ."</strong>" ."</td>";
$body .= "<tr><td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>Simply pay for 4 weeks storage when you move in and we'll give you an extra 4 weeks storage completely free!</td></tr>";

$body .= "<tr><td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>Kind Regards, </td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td style= 'padding-left:21px;'>Store Manager </td></tr>";

$body .= "</table>";
$body .= "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Try adding min-width:595px to one of your full-width td. The Gmail doesn't obey the regular width style and seem to only obey min-width on a cell.

Comment: Thanks @Narong for your comment. Unfortunately it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not knowledgeable enough about PHP to give you any tips, but I see quite a few things wrong with the static HTML bits.

```
<td style='text-align: center; text-align: middle; vertical-align: middle;      vertical-align: center'>
```

Here, you've set the vertical align twice. `vertical-align: center` isn't valid and should be removed. I would also add `min-width:595px` to this style declaration.

```
<table rules="all" style="border-color: #fff; font-family: Arial; width:595px; font-size:115%; background-color:#ffffff;" cellpadding="10"; position:relative; left:"20">
```

Instead of `border-color: #fff`, just create the entire border. `border: 3px solid #ffffff`. You have `position:relative; left:"20"` outside of your style declaration, so they should be moved. Also, you'll need to add a unit for your `left` value and remove the semi-colon in `cellpadding="10";`.

```
<td style='text-align: left; font-family: Arial; vertical-align: left;'>
```

You cannot set vertical align to left.

Also, when working in email, it is best to use the full, 6-character hex code. `border: 0px solid` can be replaced with `border: 0`. I would also suggest using absolute font sizes, rather than relative percentages.

Once again, I don't know how solid your PHP is, but seeing how there's quite a few mistakes in your HTML/CSS, I suggest getting that sorted out and your email may behave a bit nicer.

Comment: Thank you @Narong but still no luck.

Comment: Hmm.. can you grab and share the source HTML from Gmail? I'm not sure how to do it in the Gmail App, but if it's going to a Gmail address, you can grab the code from the website by clicking on the triangle next to the reply arrow -> show original